# Can I use parameterized query when "HDR=No"?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to execute some SQL queries using VBA/ADODB on a Excel Sheet, and I want to put parameters into them.

- I know how to put parameters when there are headers.
- I also know, when "HDR=No", column header names are automatically assigned (ex. "F1" for the 1st column).

So, I tried to use this assigned name as a parameter value, but something strange happened.

Here is my simplified code (data is on the sheet named "data"):

```
Dim objCn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim objRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim strSQL As String


With objCn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0;HDR=No"
    .Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
End With

strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT F1, ? FROM [data$]"

Set cmd.ActiveConnection = objCn

With cmd
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Prepared = True
End With

Set param = New ADODB.Parameter

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("param1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
cmd.Parameters("param1") = "F2"

Set objRs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set objRs = cmd.Execute

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRs
End With

Set cmd = Nothing
objRs.Close: Set objRs = Nothing
objCn.Close: Set objCn = Nothing
```

And the result is like this (on "Sheet1"):

```
  |     A     |     B
1 |           | 
2 | apple     | F2
3 | banana    | F2
4 | orange    | F2
```

I didn't get any errors, but as you can see, something happened with column 2 ("F2").

So My Question is: Can't I execute parameterized queries using assigned header names?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The result you are getting is simple to explain. `F2` is not recognized as a column name and thus interpreted as a fix string. Hence, `F2` is shown in each row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60785/1/0 What you essentially want / need is a dynamic SQL statement and thus you have to dynamically create / build `strSQL` in your VBA. What you want cannot be achieved with a parameterized query.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the method you suggested.